# Java operator precedence with += and ++ (preincrement)

Tags: java, operator-precedence

I'm trying to understand the order of evaluation for the following Java code whose output is 5:

```
int a = 1;
a += 2 + ++a;
System.out.println(a);
```

My understanding of the operator precedence (highest listed first) is:

```
++ 2
+ 4
+= 14
```

from this list

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

When the final operator is evaluated (+=), isn't the value of a 2 when the evaluation of += starts?

Comment: A compound assignment expression of the form `E1 op= E2` is equivalent to `E1 = ((E1) op (E2))`.

Comment: When in doubt regarding the _language_, check the language spec

Comment: It's definitely interesting to understand what the language does.  But also: in real code, best practice is to never mix the increment/decrement operators as part of larger expressions, even if the language happens to allow it.

Answer (score 6):

The [JLS says the following about the compound assignment operator `+=`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2)

> A compound assignment expression of the form `E1 op= E2` is equivalent
>   to `E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2))`, where `T` is the type of `E1`, except that `E1`
>   **is evaluated only once**.

So `+=` used in

```
int a = 1;
a += 2 + ++a;
```

is equivalent to

```
int a = 1;
a = (int) ((a) + (2 + ++a));
```

Fill in the blanks and this becomes

```
a = 1 + (2 + 2);
```